# How to launch a node with it's dependencies have started

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 5 launch file. Some node must start when some nodes have started , or they cannot work.

If all the nodes are written by myself, it is easy to deal with.

But now, I use some packages like moveit, whose code is not in my workspace and I donnot want to rewrite it :

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1491#issuecomment-414695741

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301136/how-to-launch-a-node-with-it%27s-dependencies-have-started/) by [itfanr](https://answers.ros.org/users/34867/itfanr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The capabilities package can be used to manage startup dependencies between launch files: http://wiki.ros.org/capabilities Most of the documentation lives on http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/capabilities/html/ . It's a bit rough, so I'd advise that you browse around a bit to get a sense for all of the things that are possible.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [itfanr](https://answers.ros.org/users/34867/itfanr/) on 2018-08-28**:
Thank you. I will read this pages and have a try with http://wiki.ros.org/capabilities.